# How did the Female Titan cut Eren's titan form?

Tags: attack-on-titan

After she killed the Levi squad, Eren transformed to fight the Female Titan. In Chapter 29, *Hammer*, it looked like Eren was having the upper hand, but then the Female Titan turned around, and with one horizontal motion, cut Eren's titan form's head in half.

How did that happen? That part wasn't clear in the anime nor the manga. Did she take a tree and smacked him? Did she harden her hand and hit him?

[image: Female Titan Wins]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See page 33, Chapter 32, "Compassion" from the manga.

The previous page followed discussion over Annie as a suspect in being the Female Titan. Mikasa asks Eren, having fought the Female Titan, if anything reminded him of Annie at all. Eren then remembers Annie's stance as a parallel to the Female Titan moving from that same stance into her kick.

The [stance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9mrC.jpg) resembles [Annie's style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP2tt.jpg) demonstrated in [Chapter 17: Illusions of Force](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3ahV.png)

The text is spoken by Mikasa to convince Eren that deep down he knows first hand how close to the similarities are.

[image: Real Answer Photo]

Comment: Ah! I see! Very good, I missed that! Thank you very much, have my +1 and the accepted answer. Hope to see you more often at the site! :)

Comment: Can you explain what happened exactly? Instead of just pointing out to the page? Right now I'm still not 100% convinced that this answer is the best one.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Hopefully, the edit is a bit more informative of what's happening.

Comment: Still, there isn't a clear "She kicked his head off" in this answer, add that and the bounty is yours :)

Answer (score 7):

**Warning This might contain spoilers.**

The move she used to finish Eren was a direct [reference](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gj_lGVqETbE&feature=player_detailpage#t=74) to a earlier scene in the anime (this has not been done in th manga as far as I know). At this point in time the viewer does not know Annie is the titan. The fight move used there resembles her fighting moves used during the training. this is one of the clue's beside the face resemblance of the titan to Annie. Some deeper information on this, the move she used is a karate move from the original Kata's. As stated in the video linked she has been trained in martial arts by her father.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

As I recall there was an reaction of fist movement (in the anime).
Probably harden her hand and got the tree *on the way* when cutting his head off.

Comment: but she did a kick not a fist hit